# Alternative to Google Local Search to get Restaurants nearby

Tags: api, google-maps, geolocation

I was looking for a REST api that can give a list of nearby restaurants. Google has deprecated its Local Search api and google places does not have many listings yet.
I found SimpleGeo(https://simplegeo.com/docs/api-endpoints/simplegeo-places#search) and it has a decent number of listings. I just want to know if anyone knows of something better. I already know of many such apis for the USA and I am looking for places outside the USA too like Singapore.

Thanks

Comment: Foursquare might be worth looking at, though I don't think you can filter by category, just keywords (https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/venues/search)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [MapQuest Search API Web Service](http://developer.mapquest.com/web/products/dev-services/search-ws) offers place (POI) data that is broken down by category and is decent in the United States.  I'm not sure how much data is available for Singapore, but it might be worth a look!